# Is it possible to replace member function to a noop function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I write c++ with c++11 and have a question as title.

Ex.

```
class Hi {
public:
Hi(){};
test() {cout << "test" << endl;};
}

void noop(){
; // noop
};

int main(){
 Hi hi();
 hi.test = noop; // just example, not real case

 return 0;
}
```

Is that possible to replace test() of class Hi to a noop function in runtime!? Thanks.

Comment: No, it isn't. Those are bound at compile time. Just a suggestion: Research the term "XY problem", you may be presenting one here.

Comment: Possible directions: `Strategy Pattern` ,`callback` or `callable`.

Comment: Not directly, but you probably want to look info function pointers and C++ function objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace any function at runtime, whether class member or not.

However, you can achieve the desired effect by using a variable.
(This is yet another example of the "add a level of indirection" method of solving problems.)

Example:

```
class Hi {
public:
    Hi(): test([this]() { do_test(); }) {}
    std::function<void()> test;
    void do_test() { cout << "test" << endl; }
};

void noop(){}

int main(){
 Hi hi;
 hi.test(); // Outputs 'test'
 hi.test = noop;
 hi.test(); // Does nothing
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Does require `#include <functional>` for `std::function`.

Comment: Does std::function belong to the term callback or callable?

Comment: If use this scenario, does performance impact huge?! Or just the same with using callback/strategy pattern?

Comment: @code_worker Some call it "callable". A callback is something you hand to some other entity for it to call when (and if) it needs to.

Comment: You wouldn't do this in very performance-sensitive code (that is, when a few microseconds matter), but most people don't encounter that level of performance sensitivity in their entire careers. (And this is an instance of the "strategy" pattern.)

Comment: @code_worker And on the point of performance-sensitivity, compared to what? The biggest loss is from losing a statically determined function call, so anything that can change `test` is going to have a performance hit.

Comment: @Caleth I'm curious about comparing with function pointer or strategy pattern

Answer (score 0):

You have to think object oriented. In this case you have to elevate your function to be an object we can name it MethodClass then your function in the class Hi will be a pointer to that class. Below a simple example

```
#include <memory>

class BaseMethodClass
{
public:
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class MethodClass1 : public BaseMethodClass
{
public:
    virtual void method() 
    { 
        // your implementation here 
    }
};

class MethodClass2 : public BaseMethodClass
{
public:
    virtual void method() 
    { 
        // your implementation here
    }
};
        
class Hi 
{
public:
    Hi() { method = nullptr; };

    void setMethod(BaseMethodClass* m) { method.reset(m); }

    void test() { if (method) method->method(); };

private:
    std::shared_ptr<BaseMethodClass> method;
};

int main() 
{
    Hi hi;
    hi.setMethod(new MethodClass1());
    hi.test();
    hi.setMethod(new MethodClass2());
    hi.test();

    return 0;
}
```

This way you can override your methos as you want not just noop